# Time difference between Apple Health on iphone XR and Schwinn Trainer app

Tags: data-synchronization, timezone

I have a Schwinn recumbent exercise bike that uses blue tooth to update the Schwinn Trainer app on my iphone XR.  The Schwinn trainer app automatically updates Apple Health.  My problem is, that when I look at Apple Health, it shows the time of my exercise with the time an hour later than I actually rode the bike.  That causes the exercise to show up on the next day in the Lose-It app if I complete my exercise after 11:00 PM.  The time on my exercise bike, the Schwinn Trainer app and my iphone are all in sync.  Does Apple Health have it's own time zone setting?

Answer (score 1):

Apple Health does not have it's own time zone setting. It will respect the time zone provided by the app saving the workout. If you go to Health > Workouts > Show All Data and open the workout, there will be a Time Zone entry. My time zones currently show "Eastern Standard Time" for workouts completed yesterday.

Yours should show whatever timezone you're currently in. If they don't, then they're being saved by Schwinn incorrectly. If the right time zone is shown, then compare the time listed with the time you expect.